# Is it possible to add padding or a margin to a docked Floating Action Button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As seen in the image below, my button feels uncomfortably close to the edge of the screen. Is there a way to move the button further away from the edge of the screen with an offset while keeping the notch look? If I add padding to the button it moves the button correctly but the notch gets messed up..

[image]

Code for reference:

```
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 70.0,
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: Container(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Icon(Icons.menu),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
```

What it looks like if I use margin or padding on the button:
[image]

Comment: You can simply write your own `FloatingActionButtonLocation` :) Just take a look at the code for the end docked one and extend it to fit your needs (:

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot thanks! Is it best to just extend the FloatingActionButtonLocation class in a new file and import that?

Comment: I would suggest to just copy paste the whole code, put it in an own widget and use that. Should solve the whole problem because as everytime said "its just a widget"! :) cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I have hardcoded 100 for x range, you can modify based on your requirement

Step 1:

```
static const double fabIconHeight= 50.0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        return Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
            child:  Container(
            height: 70.0,
            )
          ),
          floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.dehaze),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation: CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation(
              constraint.maxWidth - 100,
              constraint.maxHeight - fabIconHeight - (fabIconHeight / 2)),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Step 2:

```
class CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation implements FloatingActionButtonLocation {
  final double x;
  final double y;
  const CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation(this.x, this.y);

  @override
  Offset getOffset(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    return Offset(x, y);
  }
}
```

or

```
class CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation
    implements FloatingActionButtonLocation {
  static const double fabIconHeight = 50.0;

  const CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation();

  @override
  Offset getOffset(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    return Offset(
        scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.width - 100,
        scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.height - (70.0 / 2) -
            fabIconHeight -
            (fabIconHeight / 2));
  }
}
```

[image: Bottom Nav]